# xml scraping with python with odd xml structure

Tags: python, web-scraping, xml-parsing

```
<attribute>
  <name>Index</name>
  <values>
   <zip>
     <value>323800</value>
   </zip>
   <nation>
     <value>195300</value>
   </nation>
  </values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
 <name>Value_1</name>
 <values>
  <nation>
   <value>193800</value>
  </nation>
 </values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
 <name>Value_2</name>
 <values>
  <zip>
   <value>1000</value>
  </zip>
  <nation>
   <value>2000</value>
  </nation>
 </values>
</attribute>
```

Above is an extract from a larger xml tree I am working with. I want to create a dictionary where the text for the name tag is the key and the value is the zip/value. How can I build a code to grab only the attribute names for which a zip value exists and disregard ones which do not have a zip value and only have the nation value.

My code:

```
   import urllib2
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   tree = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sample_xml.com"))
   # creating list of names
   names = node.text for node in tree.findall('.//attribute/name')]
   zip_values = [node.text for node in tree.findall('.//zip/value')]
```

From here I would combine the two lists into a dictionary. But right now the lists I am getting look like this and there is a mismatch of Keys to values:

```
   names = ('Index', 'Value_1', 'Value_2')
   zip_values = ('323800', '1000')
```

Really what I need is

```
   my_dict = ['Index':'323800', 'Value_2':'1000']
```

But what I get with my code is below. Is there a way to workaround this?

```
   my_dict = ['Index':'323800', 'Value_1':'1000', 'Value_2:'Na']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sample_xml.com").read())
# creating list of names

d = {}
for attribute_node in root.xpath('//attribute[./values/zip/value]'):
     d[attribute_node.xpath('./name')[0].text] = attribute_node.xpath('./values/zip/value')[0].text

print d # {'Index':'323800', 'Value_2':'1000'}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly this code works and what is the logic behind it? Would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: everything is on the `xpath` query, where it only gets attributes that later contain a `./values/zip/value`.